# Best way to access variable in a loop from a different file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that has 2 files, diff.py and login.py

Here is what I have in diff.py:

```
domains = ("rt", "tc", "mfg", "ltd")
i = 0
while i<len(domains):
   # Opens a files containing different items
    with open("Files/"+domains[i]+"-diff_list.txt", 'r') as f:
        g = f.readlines()
        newList = map(lambda s: s.strip(), g)
        print "New " +domains[i]+" List: ", newList
    f.close()
    i += 1
```

Here is what I have in login.py:

```
import diff
host = diff.newList
hostDomain = diff.domains

while i < len(host):
    print "\nLogging into", host[i], "\n"
    login(user, password, host[i], timeout)
    ** Code omitted: Applying setting for that domains ** 
    i += 1
```

As you can see the issue is I will always get only "ltd" domain hosts as each loop overwrites newList variable with new info and since "ltd" is the last item, it always returns only that.

What is the best way I can access all items for each domain separately? I do not want all items in one list and would like to keep them in separate variables.

I was leaning towards dynamic variables but heard its a bad idea .. ofcourse this doesn't work but I was thinking doing this:

```
newList+domain[i] = map(lambda s: s.strip(), g)
#I was hoping this would give me 4 variables .. 
#newListrt, newListtc, newListmfg and newListltd
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables, here you want a container of *containers* e.g. a list of lists... Are your while loops simply meant to iterate once over each domain? If so, you probably should just use for-loops. Note diff.py, as written, is an infinite loop. Also note, you don't need to `.close` files that are opened using `with`

Comment: Yes, while loop iterate over each domain and has a corresponding diff file already saved with that domain name.  I fixed the infinite loop, paste error.  I don't know what you mean by use list of lists.  I am very new to python.

Comment: You have a list that contains other lists. Or you can use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need 2 files for the example you provided. If you need to split up large code then you should write functions. Without knowing what your entire code is doing below is an example re-written in the way I describe.

```
domains = ["rt", "tc", "mfg", "ltd"]

def get_diff_lists():
    result = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        result = map(lambda s: s.strip(), f.readlines())

    return result

for domain in domains:
    hosts = get_diff_list("Files/" + domain + "-diff_list.txt")

    for host in hosts:
        login(user, password, host, timeout)
```

As you stated these need to be in seperate files then you can use functions and generators to acheive this.

File #1

```
domains = ["rt", "tc", "mfg", "ltd"]

def get_diff_list():
    for domain in domains:
        with open("Files/" + domain + "-diff_list.txt", 'r') as f:
            yield map(lambda s: s.strip(), f.readlines())
```

File #2

```
from diff import get_diff_list

for diff_list in get_diff_list():
    for host in diff_list:
        login(user, password, host, timeout)
```

If you find an error I'm doing this off the top of my head.

I suggest reading some basic programming books as this isn't specific to Python.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to keep them in a different file.  I have some other code in both files and need to keep them in separate files.

Comment: You probably need to split the work in to functions then... I will attach an example.

Comment: Thanks, I went with your first suggestion!!